# Delphi project hierarchy comming from .net background

Tags: .net, delphi

Comming from a C# background I'm now trying to learn Delphi.
There are many similarities, but one of the first road blocks I'm facing now is my project hierarchy.

In .net I've got the following

```
  Solution
   |-Project1 (.dll)
   |-Project2 (.exe)
```

I used to also organise them like that in my folder structure.
But I can't find the equivalent in Delphi. What is a Solution called and what are my projects.

Is there a translatable concept, or how do you suggest I organise my projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know VS much, but I guess you're looking for project groups.

Open the project manager (first entry in Delphi's View menu) and see the first item in the tree view - it's the project group. You can right click on it to see some options for it. For a picture see [here](http://delphi.about.com/od/turbodelphitutorial/ss/delphi_ide_tour_7.htm).

**Edit:** If you open a project in Delphi or create a new one, it's always contained in a group. Normally this is a temporary group (called ProjectGroup1) which is discarded when you close the project. However if you add a second project to the group, Delphi forces you to save the group. You can also manually save a group, even if it contains only a single project. (I did this in older Delphi versions to avoid some oddities in Delphi's project management, especially if you dealt with packages.)

Comment: Jeps, that was what I'm looking for. By default however projects don't have to be in a group it seems. You need to manually create one if I'm not mistaking

Comment: I did indeed not yet try to add a second project. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Project Group in Delphi is the same as a solution in Visual Studio.